# Change App.config during installation

Tags: c#, app-config

I have XML-file with settings like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="UpdateReportService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <UpdateReportService.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Path" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Branch" serializeAs="String">
                <value>200</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="b204" serializeAs="String">
                <value>192.168.1.55</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="b200" serializeAs="String">
                <value>192.168.0.83</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Hour" serializeAs="String">
                <value>11</value>
            </setting>
        </UpdateReportService.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

And I'd like to change some values to values typed by user during install program.

I find example on VB and try convert it to c#:

```
namespace InstallConfigurator
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class SettingsClass : Installer
    {
        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"].ToString() + "UpdateReportService.exe");

            ClientSettingsSection applicationSettingsSection = (ClientSettingsSection)config.SectionGroups["applicationSettings"].Sections["UpdateReportService.Properties.Settings"];

            SettingElement Elem = applicationSettingsSection.Settings["Branch"];

            applicationSettingsSection.Settings.Remove(Elem);


            Elem.Value.ValueXml.InnerXml = "30000";
            applicationSettingsSection.Settings.Add(Elem);

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        }
    }
}
```

But get error "inaccessible due to its protection level" at this place:

```
SettingElement Elem = applicationSettingsSection.Settings["Branch"];
```

So, is it possible on c# to access to section  in App.config and to change it.

---

**Upd. 2012.02.10**

i've solved problem this way:

```
namespace InstallConfigurator
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class SettingsClass : Installer
    {
        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            string xml = Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"].ToString() + "UpdateReportService.exe.config";

            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(xml);
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
            XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);

            foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select(@"/configuration/applicationSettings/UpdateReportService.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='Branch']/value"))
            {
                nav.SetValue(Context.Parameters["BRANCH"].ToString());
            }

            foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select(@"/configuration/applicationSettings/UpdateReportService.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='Path']/value"))
            {
                nav.SetValue(Context.Parameters["PATH"].ToString());
            }

            document.Save(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered token replacement or the .NET 4 transforms http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand how it works and how it helps me

Comment: did you read through the link I provided?

Comment: Yes, of course. It is about convert XML to XSLT with plugin. Yes? But don't understand how XSLT will help me. I am sorry once again.

Comment: No probs.  What is offered is a way to build the config differently based on the mode you are building in.  So it is token replacement at build time, through T4 templates.  So, you are able to transform the config for environment specific settings.  And this is out-of-the-box with .NET 4.

Comment: But there is not "Add Config Transform" in context menu. How to transform XML to XSLT and back to XML via c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a similar project, I'm doing it in a slightly different way:

1. Ship your setup with *no* "myapp.exe.config" file.
2. Instead, ship a "myapp.exe.config.default" file that contains placeholders like "`{Branch}`".
3. During setup, load the "myapp.exe.config.default" as a string into memory.
4. Replace the placeholders with the actual values (e.g. your "`30000`").
5. Write the replaced string as the actual file "myapp.exe.config".
6. Bonus: Before writing the config check whether any existing config file is present and copy it as a backup to keep the previous version.

This runs pretty smooth in our applications.

Comment: Thank you for solution. I certainly will try it. But I'm wondering whether there is standard way to operate with App.config

Comment: @gouph I'll guess there are other ways. To me, it was a matter of time, and it turned out I got it developed quickly and it worked perfectly.

Comment: How you exclude myapp.exe.config? (for ship setup with no "myapp.exe.config")

Comment: @gouph In my [NSIS installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), I simply omit "myapp.exe.config" from being packaged into the setup.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude config in standard Visual Studio Installer Project?

Comment: @gouph Never used this kind of setup; even if you cannot exclude, simple ship it and overwrite it later with your runtime-configured configuration file ("myapp.exe.config.default").

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But why "never used this kind of setup"?

Comment: @gouph I found it way to unflexible :-)